# Leer una base de datos para determinar si, insertar datos o no

Tags: php, symfony3

Estoy insertado los datos de un directorio que ya recorrió, pero si quiero volver a recorrer el mismo directorio con diferentes archivos adentro, no quiero que los archivos que ya fueron leídos y almacenados se almacenen de nuevo en la base de datos.

alguna idea.. que puedan compartir.

```
foreach ($iterator as $regex) {
    echo $regex->getPath() ." -- ". $regex->getFilename() ." -- ". $regex->getSize() ." -- ". 
         $regex->getExtension() ." -- ". $regex->getType() . " -- " . date("Y-m-d | H:i:s", filemtime($regex)) . "\n";

    $directorio = new Directorio();
    $directorio -> setRuta($regex->getPath())
                -> setNombre($regex->getFilename())
                -> setExtencion($regex->getExtension())
                -> setTipo($regex->getType()) 
                -> setSize($regex->getSize())
                -> setFechaM(date("Y-m-d | H:i:s", filemtime($regex)));
    $entityManager -> persist($directorio);
  }
```

Comment: Porque no vas almacenando y comparando en un arreglo las rutas y nombres de ficheros?

Comment: En este caso, quiero que si se encuentra  almacenado en la base de datos aparesca como procesado y si es carga nueva, aparesca como procesando

Comment: <?
$archivos=array();
if(!in_array($regex->getPath(),$archivos)){
    $archivos[]=$regex->getPath();
    echo "procesando";
}else{
    echo "procesado";
}
?>

Comment: gracias, si me funciono tu manera de solucionar, ahora implementare para almacenar en db

Comment: Genial @Paulo Mayoral mucho exito y buena vibra!!!

Comment: ..y Buena.. Vibreeee!!!